# Format donut chart title amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I was wondering if there is a way to have css styling inside of this chart title.

```
chart.allLabels = [{
    'text': "<strong style='color:#666;font-size:18px'>80</strong>", 
    'align': 'center', 
    'y': '100'
}];
```

This just shows as the literal string instead of styling the `<strong>` tag.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think inline css is not possible. But you could turn on the class name generation, give the label an ID and then use an external css style on that class.

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since labels on the chart are SVG nodes, they do not support HTML and related CSS.

Looking at your example, it seems that you need to apply the following to the whole label:

- Make it bold
- Set color to #666
- Set font size to 18

All this is doable with [label's properties](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Label):

```
chart.allLabels = [ {
  "text": "80",
  "align": "center",
  "y": "100",
  "bold": true,
  "size": 18,
  "color": "#666"
} ];
```

Another option is to use CSS, as @gerric suggested in a comment.

Comment: I ended up having to style a little bit more than just that 80 in there in the end, so I ended up just positioning a div in the chart and styled it with css. You did answer the question that I asked thank you!